# ckeditor angular ControlValueAccessor

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I am trying to create a component that implements the ControlValueAccessor. The custom form control will implement a div that will become a ckeditor control that will then used Forms validator but It will not call the ngAfterViewInit on the custom-element and not create the ckeditor control. Should I have the ng-container tag?

view for custom-element

```
<ng-container *ngIf="controlGroup.controls.value">
    <Editor [formControl]="controlGroup.controls.value">
    </Editor>
</ng-container>
```

Component

```
import { Component, forwardRef, NgZone, EventEmitter, Inject, Input, Output, } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl  } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'Editor',
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => Editor),
            multi: true
        }
    ],
    template: `<div [attr.id]="editorId" contenteditable="true"
                style="width: 100% !important; overflow: hidden"
                class="form-control sentence-part-values-inline sentence-part-values-inline-textbox-number">
                </div>`,
})



export class Editor implements ControlValueAccessor {
    @Input() public model: OrderTemplateTool.Core.Sentences.EmeticRisks.RegimenDescriptorSentencePartModel;
    getModel(): OrderTemplateTool.Core.Sentences.EmeticRisks.RegimenDescriptorSentencePartModel {
        return this.model;
    }
    editorId: string;   

    @Output() public modelchange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    public onModelChange(): void {
       // this.validate();
        this.modelchange.next(this.getModel());
    }

    constructor(@Inject(NgZone) private ngZone: NgZone) { this.editorId = "regimen-descriptor-" + (<any>window).newGuid();    }

    onChange: any = () => { }
    onTouch: any = () => { }
    val = ""

    set value(val) {
        if (val !== undefined && this.val !== val) {
            this.val = val
            this.onChange(val)
            this.onTouch(val)
        }

    }

    writeValue(value: any) {
        this.value = value
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: any) {
        this.onChange = fn
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
        this.onTouch = fn
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {


        var self = this;

        this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
            console.log('Procssing ngZone');
            (<any>window).CKEDITOR.config.autoParagraph = false;
            console.log('ngAfterViewInit');
            console.log(this.editorId);
            if (!(<any>window).CKEDITOR.instances[this.editorId]) {
                (<any>window).CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
                (<any>window).CKEDITOR.inline(self.editorId, {
                    enterMode: 2,
                    toolbar: [
                        {
                            name: 'basicstyles', groups: ['basicstyles', 'cleanup'],
                            items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript']
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'source',
                            items: ['Sourcedialog']
                        }
                    ],
                    removeButtons: '',  //override default value from config.js of CKEDITOR,
                    extraPlugins: 'sourcedialog'
                });

                let editor = (<any>window).CKEDITOR.instances[self.editorId];
                console.log(editor);                  (<any>window).CKEDITOR.instances[this.editorId].setData(this.model.Value);
                                    (<any>window).CKEDITOR.instances[this.editorId].on("change", () => {
                    self.model.Value = (<any>window).CKEDITOR.instances[self.editorId].getData();    
                    var editorName = this.editorId;                        (<any>window).CKEDITOR.instances[editorName].updateElement();    
                    self.onModelChange();    
                });

                (<any>window).CKEDITOR.instances[this.editorId].on("instanceReady", (ev) => {
                    var editor = ev.editor;
                    editor.setReadOnly(false);
                });
            }
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
            var editor = (<any>window).CKEDITOR.instances[this.editorId];
            if (editor) {
                editor.destroy(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `formControlName`/`formGroupName`/`formArrayName` name without having a parent(or ancestor) `formGroup` directive.

This means that you'll need to have something like this:

```html
<form [formGroup]="yourFormGroup">
 <!-- ... -->
 <custom-element formControlName="name"></custom-element>
 <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

However, if you don't want to worry about including it anywhere else, you can use the `formControl` directive:

```html
<custom-element [formControl]="yourFormControlInstance"></custom-element>
```

Comment: when I use formControl I get this error core.umd.js:2838 EXCEPTION: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute

Comment: Did you add the name attribute as well? Does is still show the error then?

Comment: you mean <Editor [formControl]="controlGroup.controls.Value" >
</Editor>

Comment: Never mind, you don't need the name attribute. Is the `controlGroup.controls.Value` control defined at that point ?

Comment: It should be is there a way I can find out for sure?

Comment: That error indicates that the control is not defined/found. Try wrapping the comp into an ng-container with ngIf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213877/discussion-between-jefferson-and-andrei-gtej).

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this,
html file ->

```
<ckeditor
        [config]="editorConfig" [editor]="Editor"
        required formControlName="content"
        data="" name="text"
      >
      </ckeditor>
```

ts file ->

```
public editorConfig = {
    placeholder: 'Question Content'
  };

let form = this.fb.group({
      content: ['', [
        Validators.required
      ]]
    });
```